# Database changes are not vsiisble after executing migrate.exe

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6.1. I used code-based migration i.e. Migrate.exe to update my database (Add a new property to table). Migrate.exe executed fine and I did refresh on my SQL Server database but the newly added column was not visible.
I inserted a row into the table and checked table and found that now newly column is added to the table.
I would like to know why this newly created column not visible immediately after executing migrate.exe and why I have to hit database to see my update model changes?

**Please respond.**

I have used below database context and initializer.

```
public class AMLDBContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Property> Properties { get; set; }


    public AMLDBContext()
    {
         Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AMLDBContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().HasKey(s => new { s.PropertyName, s.TemplateId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReturnAttribute>().HasKey(s => new { s.AttributeName, s.TemplateId });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
```

}

I used below command for migrate.exe.

```
migrate.exe AutoDbUpgrade.exe  /StartUpDirectory:"C:\TestProject\AutoDbUpgrade\AutoDbUpgrade\bin\Debug"  /startupConfigurationFile=”AutoDbUpgrade.exe.config” /verbose
```

Comment: once the migration is complete, the schema should be updated and run the migration whenever a context on the database is initialized... did you run update-database? I don't really know what Migrate.exe is.

Comment: Instead of using update-database, I used Migrate.exe. Please checked below link for Migrate.exe. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj618307.aspx

Comment: are you able to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This sounds like really odd behavior and I'd be interested to see if it can be reproduced in a simple way.

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct Migrate.exe? also on the correct database? this sounds like the migration did not succeed and your schema was altered by DbContext initializer.

Comment: I am using Migrate.exe from EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\ and i checked the database is correct.

Comment: I have development environment database access but dont have access to production environment so to update production environment database, I have used code based migration using Migrate.exe so that production guyz can update database using Migrate.exe via command line. Production guyz dont have visual studio . Do you have any better approach for same?  Please advise.